# Selecting XML Node and its children. Thereby getting their values X++, AX09

Tags: xml, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, xmlnode

My XML code is:

`<ParentNode>
    <Node>
        <Name1>2003</Name1>
        <Name2>20030630</Name2>
        <Name3>20140225</Name3>
        <Name4>46944000</Name4>
        <Name5>94750099</Name5>
    </Node>
</ParentNode>`

'
But i can't the values of name1, name2 etc.
I have tried almost everything, but it comes up empty or XMLNode not initzialied

I have been told to use selectSingleNode so i have tried everything it:
info(strfmt("%1",levelOne.selectSingleNode('//Name1')));
 info(strfmt("%1",levelOne.selectSingleNode('Node/Name1')));
But nothing works

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/194074) in AX Community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the code below - this will print '2003' to the infolog.

```
public static client void SomeAotJob()
{
    str xml;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc;
    XmlNode xmlNode;
    ;

    xml = @'<ParentNode>
    <Node>
        <Name1>2003</Name1>
        <Name2>20030630</Name2>
        <Name3>20140225</Name3>
        <Name4>46944000</Name4>
        <Name5>94750099</Name5>
    </Node>
</ParentNode>';


    xmlDoc = XmlDocument::newXml(xml);
    xmlNode = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode('//Name1');
    info(xmlNode.innerText());
}
```